# Nesting "WHERE IN" (or AND, OR statements) SQLite

Tags: sqlite, nested, where-in

I'd like to have a SELECT query that gets 8 specific combinations of user1 & user2 (and that combination of user2 & user1 is also worth having and not redundant). The "IN" statement seemed worthwhile.

Directly related questions.
1. Can "WHERE IN" statements be nested?

1. If not, how might I most effectively/ most easily structure a query so that I might specify (for 4 pairs where user1 and user2 switch position - 8 combinations):  `(where user1 = billy AND user2 = sue) OR (where user1 = sue AND user2 =billy) OR (user1 = jack AND user2 = jill) OR (user1 = jill AND user2 = jack)`...etc ?

[At this point it seems easier to run the query and grep out the pertinent info.]

Current thought:

```
sqlite3 -header -separator , some.db "SELECT DISTINCT programquality.time, simscores.user1, simscores.user2, simscores.simscore, programquality.gf, programquality.ga, programquality.pq FROM simscores LEFT JOIN programquality ON programquality.time = simscores.time AND programquality.username = simscores.user1 WHERE programquality.pq IS NOT NULL WHERE simscores.user1 IN ("abraham","billy","carl","dave","ethan","frank","george","harry") WHERE simscores.user2 IN ("abraham","billy","carl","dave","ethan","frank","george","harry");"
```

I've used this, but some non-relevant data is displayed.

```
sqlite3 -header -separator , some.db 'SELECT DISTINCT programquality.time, simscores.user1, simscores.user2, simscores.simscore, programquality.gf, programquality.ga, programquality.pq FROM simscores LEFT JOIN programquality ON programquality.time = simscores.time AND programquality.username = simscores.user1 WHERE (simscores.user1  = "billy" OR simscores.user1 = "suzy" OR simscores.user1 = "john") AND (simscores.user2  = "billy" OR simscores.user2 = "suzy" OR simscores.user2 = "john") AND programquality.pq IS NOT NULL AND programquality.time IS NOT NULL;'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query [can have only one `WHERE` clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), but that expression can combine multiple conditions with `AND` or `OR`:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE programquality.pq IS NOT NULL AND
      simscores.user1 IN ('abraham', 'billy', ...) AND
      simscores.user2 IN ('abraham', 'billy', ...)
```

However, these `IN` expressions do not allow you to match *specific* values for `user1` and `user2`.
You cannot avoid listing all combinations you want.

However, you can simplify the expression somewhat by check the combined names for valid combinations:

```sql
... WHERE ... AND
          simscores.user1 || '+' || simscores.user2
           IN ('billy+sue', 'sue+billy',
               'jack+jill', 'jill+jack',
               ...)
```